# @reach/router: how to get the current route / page?

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

How does one get the current route for reach router. In react router one would get that through the params?

The docs don't currently show an example how to do this.

Comment: In the `this.props.location` in your component you have your location details including the current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the this.props.location as it's passed down to the component:

https://reach.tech/router/api/Router

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, use the `useLocation` hook (since [1.3.0](https://github.com/reach/router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v130)):

```
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"

const useAnalytics = () => {
    const location = useLocation()

    useEffect(() => {
        ga.send(['pageview', location.pathname])
    }, [])
}
```

Ref: https://reach.tech/router/api/useLocation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just import `useLocation` from `@reach/router` and assign it to a const use it in your code as below.

```
import React from "react";

import { useLocation } from "@reach/router";

const YourPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <Page>
      <div>{(location.pathname = "/terms/")}</div>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default YourPage;
```